# Why is Method#arity called, well, arity?

Tags: ruby, methods, terminology

In Ruby, I know that `Method#arity` will return a value representing the number of arguments accepted by a method, however I do not know why it is called arity. Can anyone provide some insight into why it would exist in such a seemingly random namespace? Also, how do you pronounce it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because that's actually the name for it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity

I pronounce it AIR-i-TEE like in polarity.

Comment: Funny, I pronounce it ARR-i-TEE, like in.... er... polarity. ;)

The first syllable is the sound from "Harry" or "Larry" for me (I'm Australian)